# How to change defuzzification method in Tipping Problem?

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic, skfuzzy

I tried the Tipping problem posted on the following website as an example. It works and there is no problem. But I am not sure how to change the defuzzification method in new API. I believe the default method is centroid. How can I check other methods using new API?

https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_tipping_problem_newapi.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution, I found:

```
tip = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 26, 1), 'tip', defuzzify_method='centroid')
```

You can check other methods in API.